# How do I force BIND9 to bind to a specific IP?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, localhost

This is my setup:

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet 10.0.2.0/24 scope global lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

'lo' is magical in the sense that that 10.0.2.0/24 line actually creates ~250 bindable addresses. Most daemons bind to these without trouble. However, this does not work in my BIND9-config:

```
listen-on port 53 { 10.0.2.15; };
```

(I've tried without "port 53" too). The problem is that for BIND, listen-on is like a "binding whitelist", that it matches to all IPs it can find on all interfaces. In this case, it does not find 10.0.2.15 on any interfaces, so it does not bind.

Can anyone recommend a workaround? I should point out that this is a testing setup on which I am moving things around all the time so I would prefer a solution that does not involve too many moving parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of testing...  Bind doesn't appear to work the way you have observed other daemons working. I have noted 2 workarounds the first is add an additional address to `lo` to allow bind to bind to it

```
ip addr add 10.0.2.15/32 dev lo
```

The second is to change the address bind listens on to `10.0.2.0`

Comment: I had found both of these too. Neither solve my problem, but given that I'm ready to accept that there is no answer, I'll accept this one :)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do as a workaround for testing is to create a virtual interface lo:1 and assign the address 10.0.2.15 to it and bring it up

Comment: Yes - i know that this works. But it's not what I want :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that. The fact that the `loopback interface` **responds** on every ip on the configured subnet (i.e. `ping 10.0.2.15` works as expected), doesn't mean **every** IP is bindable.

Try binding to, for example, `127.0.0.2` and see if it works.

I think the only solution is doing as @m0ntassar said.

Comment: the IPs are bindable just fine - every other daemon I've tried has absolutely no trouble with binding.